# How to execute SQL Statement to make it as source and Load into Destination table in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a  table  **dbo.Test**    whose columns  (ID,Query_Column)

```
ID   Query_Column

1    SELECT CustomerKey, FirstName, LastName, MaritalStatus, Gender FROM CUSTOMER_DETAILS
```

In Query column I have  a  select  statement  which have  some data.

Now  In my SSIS Package  I want to make it as  Source  columns  and Load  into Destination Table dynamically.

```
**Source**             **Destination** 

CustomerKey       CustomerKey
FirstName         FirstName
LastName          LastName
MaritalStatus     MaritalStatus
Gender            Gender
```

Now  In my SSIS Package  I want to make it as  Source  columns  and Load  into Destination Table dynamically.

Can anyone suggest me  on this  .

Comment: I don't know SSIS well enough, but from what I do know: I doubt it. You could always use a `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ...`.

Comment: I'm looking  in SSIS . In SQL we can do many ways @HoneyBadger thanks  for the  reply

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use "Execute SQL Task" instead of "Data Flow Task".
In this component you can use an SQL Query.

Please find below a sample of query to do the stuff :

```
declare @query varchar(1000);

select  @query =  [Query_Column] FROM Test where ID = 1 ;

set @query = concat(@query,' into temp_table');

exec(@query)
```

after that you have can :

- create a data flow from temp_table
  or
- enrich the sql query above to feed the expected table from temp_table

[image]

Comment: is temp table  will work in OLEDB Source  ?

Answer (score 0):

In your Execute SQL Task, use a stored procedure like below :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Testtable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.Testtable; 

DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(100)
DECLARE @table varchar(75)
DECLARE @sqldisplay varchar(1000)

SET @columnList = (SELECT SUBSTRING(Query_Column, CHARINDEX('SELECT', Query_Column) +6
, CHARINDEX('FROM',Query_Column) - CHARINDEX('SELECT', Query_Column) - Len('FROM')-2)
FROM dbo.Mytab)
SET @table = (SELECT SUBSTRING(Query_Column, CHARINDEX('FROM',Query_Column) + LEN('FROM'), LEN(Query_Column))
FROM dbo.Mytab)
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT' +@columnlist + 'INTO dbo.Testtable FROM' + @table
SET @sqldisplay = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Testtable'
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
EXEC (@sqldisplay)
```